# Paypal order status issue in magento (INR to USD convertion)

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am customized paypal module for INR currency

So I converted INR amount to USD amount for paypal transaction

Paypal payment is working properly.

Issue is order status changed to Suspected Fraud.

How to change return amount from paypal before order status change

Below code is amount conversion before paypal transaction

```
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $result['amount'] = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($result['amount'], 'INR', 'USD'), 2);
        $result['tax'] = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($result['tax'], 'INR', 'USD'), 2);
        $result['shipping'] = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($result['shipping'], 'INR', 'USD'), 2);
        $result['discount_amount'] = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($result['discount_amount'], 'INR', 'USD'), 2);
        $result['discount_amount_cart'] = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($result['discount_amount_cart'], 'INR', 'USD'), 2);
```

Please suugest any solution to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the Base Currency?

Comment: @Dushyant  INR is a base currency

Comment: I do not think so PayPal accepts INR as base currency